# System.Net.Sockets throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets

Quick summary: App in VS 2010 VB.NET and currently running at the Win 2008 server for testing. It is a multi-threaded (8 threads) app and reads the data from .NET socket.

Details:

```
Public Class StateObject
    Public workSocket As Socket = Nothing ' Client socket.
    Public BufferSize As Integer = 20000    ' Size of receive buffer.   Orig: 20000
    Public buffer(20000) As Byte            ' Receive buffer.           Orig: (20000)
    Public sb As New StringBuilder()      ' Received data string.
End Class 'StateObject

Private Sub Read_Callback(ar As IAsyncResult)

    Dim state As StateObject = CType(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
    Dim bytesRead As Long = 0
    Dim client As Socket = state.workSocket

    SyncLock state

    Try
    ' Read data from the remote device.
    bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar)

    If bytesRead > 0 Then ' There might be more data, so store the data received so far.

    SyncLock state.sb
    **state.sb.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead))**
    End SyncLock

    If state.sb.Length > 1 Then
    SyncLock state.sb
    response = state.sb.ToString()
    **state.sb.Clear()**

    End SyncLock
    End If


    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, _
    AddressOf Read_Callback, state)
    Else ' All the data has arrived; put it in response.

    If state.sb.Length > 1 Then
    SyncLock state.sb
    response = state.sb.ToString()
    state.sb.Clear()

    End SyncLock

    End If

    readDone.Set()
    End If
    Catch e As Exception
    AppEventLog.WriteEntry("SocketManager.Read_Callback: (LineNum=" & Err.Erl.ToString & ") " & e.Message & vbCrLf & _
    "bytesRead = " & bytesRead.ToString & vbCrLf & _
    "state.sb.Length = " & state.sb.Length.ToString & vbCrLf & _
    "state.sb.Capacity = " & state.sb.Capacity.ToString & vbCrLf & _
    "state.sb.MaxCapacity = " & state.sb.MaxCapacity.ToString & vbCrLf & _
    "state.workSocket.Available = " & state.workSocket.Available.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error)
    End Try
    End SyncLock

    state = Nothing

End Sub 'Read_Callback
```

And here is the error log in Windows Event View:

```
SocketManager.Read_Callback: (LineNum=80) Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
bytesRead = 20000
state.sb.Length = 0
state.sb.Capacity = 20000
state.sb.MaxCapacity = 2147483647
state.workSocket.Available = 0


**LineNum = 80 causes most errors but sometime occurs at LineNum = 130** (see highlighted lines above)
```

Questions:

1. Is this caused by StringBuilder or else?
2. What is the solution?

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?  (In a manner we can recognize it without the whole program)

Comment: state.sb.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead))

Comment: Any chance you could log the last 100 or so bytesRead and state.buffer addresses (if there is such) before this call?  Be sure to include timetamp (to millisecond) and which socket is being operated on.